# Chaining Promises In Loop

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am struggling to loop through the array `periods` whilst querying the DB and inserting data. The problem I am facing can be seen on the 5th from last line. The final `db.queryPromise` does not get invoked.

Please see comment 5 lines from the bottom for where the problem is.

```
// db.js

const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : ****,
    password : ****,
    database : ****,
});

module.exports = connection;

module.exports.queryPromise = function (args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(args, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(rows);
    });
  });
};

module.exports.connectPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve();
  });
});

// app.js
const db = require('../config/db');

const periods = ['1h','12h','24h','1w','1m','3m','1y','all'];
const sqlCarIds = `SELECT id FROM car_models ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200;`;

return db.queryPromise(sqlCarIds)
.then((rows) => {
  const car_ids = [];
  for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    car_ids.push(rows[i].car_id);
  };

  for (let i = periods.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    const sqlSnapshot = `SELECT price FROM car_models;`;

    db.queryPromise(sqlSnapshot)
    .then(([row]) => {
      if (!row) {
        throw new Error('API call found nothin');
      }

      const highPrice = row.high;
      const sqlInsert = `INSERT into price_cache (high) VALUES (` + highPrice` + )`;`

      console.log(sqlInsert); // logs correctly formed query
      db.queryPromise(sqlInsert)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('this should fire'); // doesn't fire
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Explain the scenario of *why* you're doing this and what goes wrong with your current code.

Comment: Purpose is to move data from large database to a small one where the price data is overwritten. This will allow for faster queries for the users while the server does all the filtering for them. I've commented the line which doesn't fire and where the code goes wrong - no errors, but the sqlInsert query simply isn't invoked.

Comment: @Nick Use `console.log(err)` inside `db.queryPromise` function to make sure there is no error because of the query.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax for the `sqlInsert` is invalid. You will need to write it like following example. You need to use the `${expression}` literals to add the value of an expression into a "[Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)". Your [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) doesn't get resolved because there is an error which rejects it.

```
const sqlInsert = `INSERT into price_cache (high) VALUES (${highPrice})`;
```

Comment: Sorry you're write, that was a typo in the question. Sadly no error even with correctly provided expressions, it simply doesn't invoke. The syntax is all OK, and works

Comment: can you add the source code of the `db.queryPromise` method?